# Вывести кликабельный список с результатами поиска на форме c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Стоит задача: по мере набора текста для поиска выводить список с возможными совпадениями, пусть по первым буквам текста. Или проще: ищем человека по фамилии, начинаем вводить фамилию и по мере ввода получаем фамилии начинающиеся с введенных букв. Форма windows forms C#. Я умею использовать обработчики, но не могу вывести кликабельный список.

Comment: Ловите событие KeyDown в контроле, куда вводите текст. В его обработчике по введенной строке строите запрос. Асинхронно его исполняете и результат после исполнения помещаете в обновляемый список. Никто за Вас не будет делать Вашу работу.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов обработчики расписаны, запрос построен. И список в виде List обновляется. Не могу именно **вывести** всплывающий список.

Comment: ИМХО, думаю, что я не один, кто не понял слов "...Не могу именно вывести всплывающий список...". Нужно пояснения и не в комментариях, а в тексте вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        source.AddRange(new string[]
                {
                    "Январь",
                    "Февраль",
                    "Март",
                    "Апрель",
                    "Май",
                    "Июнь",
                    "Июль",
                    "Август",
                    "Сентябрь",
                    "Октябрь",
                    "Ноябрь",
                    "Декабрь"
                });

        var textBox = new TextBox
        {
            AutoCompleteCustomSource = source,
            AutoCompleteMode =
                AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
            AutoCompleteSource =
                AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource,
            Location = new Point(200, 85),
            Width = 100,
            Visible = true
        };

        Controls.Add(textBox);
```